# optaplanner - VRP but with no depot

Tags: optaplanner, traveling-salesman

i'm working with the Multiple Vehicles Route Problem. I'm trying Optaplanner and looks good and promising.

I'm using the CVRP-32customers example, but I need to remove the "depots".

I just need to optimize a route for some salesman, where they start is not an issue to me. I just need the best 10 routes to visit my 100 customers, does not matter where they start.

I looked at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33266431/1259763), but could not take anything from it to solve my problem.

Can this be achieved with Optaplanner? Is there an alternative (hopefully free...)?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
    Federico.

Comment: Your planning problem seems to be a traveling salesman problem (TSP) rather than Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP).. Take a look at the TSP example instead VRP to give you a better idea to start building your own solution.

Comment: I disagree with @the.wizard, I don't think this is a TSP because you need multiple (e.g., 10) routes rather than just one. Does each route need to be "closed", i.e., begin and end at the same node? Or is it OK if the salesperson starts at a node, visits a bunch of other nodes, and then ends at a node that's not the start node?

Comment: Thanks the.wizard and grendelsdad. I agree with grendelsdad, I need multiple routes. It does not matter if routes are closed or not. I just need to find a near optimal solution for this scenario with no depot. Do you think it can be done? Thanks again, Federico.

Comment: @FedericoAlvarez : Ah I see.. Sorry I forget the detail that you need multiple routes (because you probably have more than 1 vehicle or salesperson).. I think I know what you need to do, first you need to alter the VRP domain model.. Then add some rule that approriate with your bussiness process.. Above all, I think your problem absolutely could be solve using optaplanner..

Comment: Thanks the.wizard. Any hint where should I start to learn about how to alter domain models? Thanks again, Federico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem absolutely could be solved using Optaplanner. You have a good start by using VRP example. Now, the first thing you need to do is of course alter the domain model class to fit your need.

1. The first class you should alter would be Vehicle class, as you said, you want to remove the depot because you don't need it in your case. So instead of having depot property inside the vehicle class, you could change it to location instead.
2. The second thing you should take care was how do you want your route to be? If it is a closed route which mean the start location was also the end of location, then you don't need to make any modification since the VRP example was a closed route. But if you desire a open route which mean the end location of your vehicle is not the start location, then you might want to alter the "distanceFromLastCustomerToDepot" rule. How you alter it, it really depends on you business process.

If you want to discuss more, feel free to join the optaplanner [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/optaplanner-dev). You could find me there using the same nickname (Wizard). 
Hope this help you, kind regards.

Comment: Thanks the.wizard. Will take a look into it and maybe post something in that forum. Best regards, Federico.

Comment: I have multiple drivers with geo coordinates and also have multiple pickup points. I want to plan a trip for each driver with a maximum of 3 (or based on vehicle capacity) pickups, drivers do not need to return to the depot. Can you give me an idea to implement this in Optaplanner? Where I can need to start?